# How to list all categories in MediaWiki main/home page

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

How to show all categories in MediaWiki Main or home page?

Comment: Do you want to create a list of all categories of the wiki, and display it on the main page? Or do you want to list all categories that the mainpage of a wiki belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

What about

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=categories&format=xml

The main page is not exactly brimming with categories.

Comment: You would probably want to start by checking [meta=siteinfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo), to see what the main page of the wiki is called, before fetching the categories